# Interpretation of Sum of Characteristic Functions

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

In probability theory, the characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is defined as

$$
\varphi_X(t) =\mathrm{E}\left(e^{\mathrm{i}tX}\right),
$$

We further know that the characteristic function of the sum of $N$ independent random variables, $Z=\sum_{k=1}^{N}X_k$, is simply 
$$
\varphi_Z(t)=\mathrm{E}\left(e^{itZ}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^N\phi_{X_k}(t).
$$

Thus, the **product** of characteristic functions has a clear interpretation in terms of the transformation of the sum of independent random variables.

For quite some time now, I am wondering whether the **sum of characteristic functions** may also have an interpretation in terms of random variables and their probability distributions?

For example, we know that the *sum* of an exponential and a standard normal random variable has the transform

$$
\varphi_{Exp(\lambda)+N(\mu,\sigma)}(t)=\frac{1}{1-i\lambda t}e^{i\mu t - \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}
$$

But is there a meaningful interpretation to a characteristic function of the form

$$
\varphi_{?}(t)=\frac{1}{1-i\lambda t}\mathbf{+}e^{i\mu t - \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}
$$

Comment: Never encountered and I would be quite surprised if there is a meaningful interpretation of it. No reason to believe so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of a characteristic function $$\varphi_X(t) =\mathrm{E}\left(e^{\mathrm{i}tX}\right),$$ implies $$\varphi_X(0) =\mathrm{E}1=1,$$ so $\varphi_X(t)+\varphi_Y(t)$ can't be a characteristic function. Of course, we can normalize it: $$\varphi_Z(t)=\frac12(\varphi_X(t)+\varphi_Y(t))=\frac12\mathrm{E}\left(e^{\mathrm{i}tX}\right)+\frac12\mathrm{E}\left(e^{\mathrm{i}tY}\right).$$ The probabilistic interpretation is obvious: you toss a fair coin, and "head" means $Z=X$, "tail" is $Z=Y$.

Comment: Yes, that makes very much sense to: A weighted sum of char. functions is simply the characteristic function inversion of a mixed distribution! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of two characteristic function cannot be a characteristic function itself… a characteristic function fullfils $\varphi(0) = 1$ and is bounded by $1$ so for the sum of two characteristic functions it holds $$\varphi_{X_1}(0) + \varphi_{X_2}(0) = 2$$ Hence two main characteristics are violated…

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right -- and I was a bit sloppy. But after rescaling by $1/\sum \phi(0)=1/N$, The result of  @Professor-Vector seems worthwile.

Comment: That's why I already upvoted :-)